# REACT Warning Unknown props parsing to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I always get this warning when i try to pass a props to child component

> Warning: Unknown prop `logout` on  tag. Remove this prop from the
>   element.

here is my code :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutUser } from '../actions/auth.action';

import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';

class Login extends React.Component {
  static muiName = 'FlatButton';

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatButton {...this.props} label="Login"
        containerElement={<Link to="/login">Setup</Link>}
        linkButton={true}
      />
    );
  }
}

const Logged = (props) => {

  const doLogout =()=>(props.logout);
  return(
    <IconMenu
      {...props}
      iconButtonElement={
        <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
      }
      targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
      anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    >
      <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" 
        onTouchTap={doLogout}
      />
    </IconMenu>
  )
};

Logged.muiName = 'IconMenu';

class MUIAppBar extends React.Component {

  state = {
    logged: (localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token') !== null),
  };

  render() {
  // when user hover the title it would turn into pointer
    const styles = {
      title: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
    };
    const { logoutUser } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title={<span style={styles.title}><IndexLink to="/">D:Vision</IndexLink></span>}
          iconElementRight={this.state.logged ? <Logged logout={logoutUser} /> : <Login />}
        />  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        logoutUser: () => (
            dispatch(logoutUser)
        )
    }
}

export default MUIAppBar =  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MUIAppBar);
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you are passing the parent props to your child where you only need one prop namely logout? See the docu: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Comment: @Chris how could i access ...newProps in logged to access my props of logoutUser?

Comment: You would still send in all your props with `<Logged logout={logoutUser} />` but before doing `<IconMenu {...props}` you need to **remove** `logout` from `props`. `props` should only contain valid *html attributes* at that point and `logout` isn't one.

Comment: @Chris i'm still getting the same error. I do this one : `const Logged = (props) => {
  let newProps = Object.assign({}, props);
     delete newProps.logoutUser;

  return(
    <IconMenu
      {...newProps}
     ..
    </IconMenu>
  )
};`

Comment: `Logged` has a `logout` prop, not a `logoutUser` prop, right? I think you are doing `delete` on something that doesn't exist. If I'm not missing something, it should be `delete newProps.logout`

Comment: @Chris wah my mistake sorry, it's work. thx you so much. :)

Comment: @Chris do i did it right?, i choose "solve my problem on the top page"